# Intake valve failure (F02) in dishwasher, anything to try?

Tags: dishwasher

I bought a dishwasher, an Indesit DFP 58T94, and the installers were terrible. They connected the pipes but left without trying because they couldn't open the water valve. They told me it had to be replaced by a plumber. I easily opened by using a pair of plyers.

To my disappointment, the dishwasher is now displaying error F02, which is water intake valve selonoid failure. The failure is also clearly observable as water keeps pouring into the dishwasher even when it's off. It looks like the valve is not closing.

I booked an engineer to come and see it. Indesit/Whirpool completely refuse to give me any useful information other than a mighty holy engineer has to be booked.

I already cut the water supply, disconnected the hose, and checked in the intake filter, which looks clean. Is there anything I can do in the hopes of getting the dishwasher running or is it DOA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says bad solenoid, then it's probably a bad solenoid.  Return it or get an exchange, if it's still under warranty.

Comment: It was brand new, so, I was trying to figure out whether anything installation-wise could be a problem. We just got it replaced.